# Accept and parsing request in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am using expressjs and I want get a request object comes form this url

```
http://www.thedomain.com/membername/category/item?item=abc
```

in server side. I am trying to use

```
// app.js
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();
app.use('/*', routes);
```

In './routes/index':

```
//'./routes/index''./routes/index'
var express = require('express');
var config = require('../config');
var router = express.Router();
var url = require('url');

/* GET category page. */
router.get('/category', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(' pathname: ',url.parse(req.url).pathname)
    res.render('index', {
        title: url.parse(req.url).pathname
        });
});
```

Actually, I have no way to get value of membername

I want to know how could I get value of membername before process item value in query string in the category router. I also want to know how to write a regex that accept all value of membername for the router which stay on the front of the category router as a pre-process module.

Thank for all your comment and answer

Comment: What do your member names look like? Are they just letters? Alphanumeric? Numbers?

Comment: We are not here to implement your requirements for you. Write your own code and come back when you have specific questions about what you did.

Comment: may be letter and number...@remus

Comment: @Tomalak...I got myown code...going to update

Answer (score 1):

```
req.get('/:memberName/category/item', function(req, res, next) {
    // do whatever you want with req.prams.memberName here...
    next();
});

req.get('/:memberName/category/item', function(req, res, next) {
    // now do whatever you want with req.query.item here...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jmar777 very simple and smart...but how do I write a router accept all of memberName request before sent it to other router...???

Comment: Hey, just updated my answer. Is that closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Yep...it is very close..but I also looking for the way to beautify routers structure.

Comment: Thank so much @jmar777

Answer (score 1):

Since you suggest you want to restrict only to letters and numbers (and perhaps _ too), use a regular expression:

```
req.get('/\w+/category/item', function(req, res, next) {
    // Access membername via req.params[0]
});
```

I've had bad luck with Express routes and regular expressions, but I believe that problem has been fixed in Express 4.0.

Comment: Thank remus...me too...:D